# Access src from public in vue

Tags: vuejs2

I need to access to src/assets/fonts/... in public/paymentVerifyCallback.html.
I've written it in this way :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "IRANSansWeb";
    src: url("../src/assets/fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb.ttf") format("truetype");
  }
```

but it doesn't work, returns " Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/src/assets/fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb.ttf "

but I have this font file in this address.
what is the problem?